# image switch on iPad - onmouseout behaviour

Tags: ipad

I can click an image and it changes, then mouseout and the image reverts:

```
<a href="#" onclick="movepicGreen('Welcome','../img/directories/Available.gif')"     onmouseover="showtip1('Welcome');showtip2('Welcome to the Course.')" onmouseout="showtip2('');showtip1('');movepicGreen('Welcome','../img/directories/main/WelcomeGreen.gif')">
img name="Welcome" border="0" src="../img/directories/main/WelcomeGreen.gif" width="250" height="18"></a></td>
```

Actually, I don't even need the revert part of the onmouseout. It will revert without it.

But on the iPad, it doesn't revert - it sticks. Why does it behave differently?

The movepicGreen routine is:

```
function movepicGreen(img_name,img_src) {
document[img_name].src=img_src;
document[img_name].onmouseout = function () {this.src='../img/directories/main/'+ img_name]+'Green.gif';}
}
```

Comment: There's no mouse on the iPad. Seriously.

Comment: I suspect though that the mouseover code is getting in the way or something on the iPad because when I click an image link below it on the page, the onclick swapped image becomes a question mark just before you leave the page. It's a little annoying and looks wrong.